Redirect after OAuth2 authorization keeps user in a loop
I am implementing OAuth2 authorization in my application with an external provider. When the user is redirected back to my application from the authorization server, my application will just redirect the user back despite using the Redirect() method to specify the URL.
Program.cs
builder.Services
    .AddAuthentication(options =>
    {
        options.DefaultAuthenticateScheme = CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
        options.DefaultSignInScheme = CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;

        options.DefaultChallengeScheme = "ExternalProvider";
    })
    .AddCookie()
    .AddOAuth("ExternalProvider", options =>
    {
        ...

        options.CallbackPath = new PathString("/auth/callback");

        ...

        options.Events.OnCreatingTicket = async context =>
        {
            HttpRequestMessage req = new(HttpMethod.Get, context.Options.UserInformationEndpoint);
            req.Headers.Accept.Add(new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json"));
            req.Headers.Authorization = new AuthenticationHeaderValue("Bearer", context.AccessToken);

            HttpResponseMessage res = await context.Backchannel.SendAsync(req, HttpCompletionOption.ResponseHeadersRead, context.HttpContext.RequestAborted);
            res.EnsureSuccessStatusCode();

            var user = JsonDocument.Parse(await res.Content.ReadAsStringAsync()).RootElement;

            context.RunClaimActions(user);

            // Save user to database if it doesn't exist

            ApplicationDbContext dbContext = context.HttpContext.RequestServices.GetRequiredService<ApplicationDbContext>();

            int userId = int.Parse(user.GetString("sub"));

            // Check if user exists

            bool userExists = (await dbContext.Users.FirstOrDefaultAsync(u => u.Id == userId)) is not null;

            if (!userExists)
            {
                // Save the user

                string username = user.GetString("preferred_username");
                string profilePicture = user.GetString("picture");

                dbContext.Users.Add(new ApplicationUser()
                {
                    Id = userId,
                    Username = username,
                    ProfilePicture = profilePicture
                });

                await dbContext.SaveChangesAsync();
            }

            context.Response.Redirect("/Home/Index"); // User is still redirected to /auth/login
        };
    });

AuthController.cs
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;

namespace Frontend.Controllers
{
    public class AuthController : Controller
    {
        public IActionResult Login()
        {
            return Challenge("ExternalProvider");
        }
    }
}

HomeController.cs
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;

namespace Frontend.Controllers
{
    public class HomeController : Controller
    {
        public IActionResult Index()
        {
            return View();
        }
    }
}

I want to return a MVC view after the authorization process is completed and I'm attempting to do it by redirecting the user to the home controller but with no success since the user will just be redirected back to the authorization.

The reason why you keep redirect is you set the   context.Response.Redirect("/Home/Index");  inside the OnCreatingTicket will not work.
The return url is set when the Challenge method called inside the AuthController .
Modify like below and then it will work well.
        var properties = new AuthenticationProperties
        {
            RedirectUri = "/home/index"
        };

        return Challenge(properties,"ExternalProvider");


It turned out redirecting from the AuthController was not necessary and it was enough to call context.Response.CompleteAsync(), although i also found this GitHub issue and now I'm unsure about the proper way of doing this.

The thing is actually there is no need to  create a AuthController, you just need to set the [Authorize] attribute, if the application find there is no cookie and not login in it will auto redirect to the  Options.AuthorizationEndpoint.

Alright, it is working but the RedirectUri is being ignored when redirected from the authorization page (it actually doesn't even appear in the query). Also would calling CompleteAsync() be the proper way of redirecting the user in the case of events like OnAccessDenied?

when you call this inside the options.Events.OnCreatingTicket?

I assume that the RedirectUri of AuthenticationProperties indicates where the user will be redirected after authorization, unless I'm wrong it is not even being added to the query.

Yes, it will add it , but it maybe will not add it through the querystring. It will use after the Events.OnTicketReceived. You could also modify it like below     googleOptions.Events.OnTicketReceived = ctx =>     {         // Redirect to the home page after login         ctx.ReturnUri = "/Home/Index";         return Task.CompletedTask;     }; });
